# Save variable to text file serverside using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to save a variable for counting the views of my personal website, I dont need to use php because its literally a viewcount. I know how to retrieve the count from the server using $.post, but how would I retrieve it (Edit: In the simplest way possible.)?
The website I'm trying to do it with is http://artsicleprojects.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you know how to retrieve from the ***server*** using post, or from the ***client*** using post?

Comment: I know how to retrieve from the server. I have a .txt file in my site serverside.

Comment: you need to clarify your question because I read it 10 times and I'm still confused as to what you want

Comment: The title is talking about saving, the text is talking about retrieving. Which one you actually want?

Comment: This would be a good time to thoroughly read [ask]

Comment: He's on the right track, [he's at least mentioning jQuery...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)

Comment: I want to save a variable onto a text file in the server

Comment: Yes, just joking, but seriously, you will need to use PHP, or some other server-side scripting (ie. (Don't say it...) JSP), because your doing something server-side. jQuery can help with making a post request, but you will need PHP

Comment: yes, the question was solved. At the top left of my website is views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need PHP for this question, because it is dealing with server-side actions. First, you need to make a server-side script to increment the text file's number. Then, you will need to make a client-side script to make a request to the server. This script increments a number in the text file every time the request is made. Anyway, here's how I would do it (Note: this code is un-tested):

PHP:

```
<?php
/*Reads and collects current count.*/
$rfile = fopen("views.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$count = fread($rfile,filesize("views.txt"));
fclose($rfile);
/*Increments the count.*/
$wfile = fopen("views.txt", "w");
$ncount = $count + 1;
fwrite($wfile, $ncount);
fclose($wfile);
?>
```

Note on code: for this code to work correctly, you may need a text file already made (views.txt), in the same directory as the PHP script, with a single "0" written in it.

---

JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
$.post("phpscript.php", function(data, status){
    console.log(status);
});
```

This also is supposed to be in the same directory as the script to work.